# Internet Explorer 11 'Compatibility View settings' in Windows 11 Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-11

Long time listener, first time caller.  Apologies if this post is bad, I'm not the savviest of web troubleshooters and only marginally a developer.

With brand new instances of Windows 11 - not upgraded from Windows 10 - there is no more Compatibility View settings option for Internet Explorer.  Long story very short:  the software my company supports was written for IE over 20 years ago and is comprised of a multitude of varying compatible levels (i.e. IE5-8) and only now are we able to rewrite for the future.  We have long required the users to jump through hoops (domain added to Compatibility View settings, Trusted Site inclusion, Low internet security (I know) etc).  In Windows 10, Edge with Internet Explorer Mode on works wonderfully because it still pulls in the IE settings.

- I have tried adding "X-UA-Compatible" tags to the pages from IE=edge
  through IE=5 in varying combinations to not fabulous results:
- I have tried modifying
  HKEY_Current_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet
  Explorer\BrowserEmulation\PolicyList by adding in the URL to no
  avail.
- I have tried to download IE11 from Microsoft, but I'm pretty
  sure when Thanos snapped his fingers IE actually did disappear from
  the halls of MS. I have searched the internet, various sites etc, but
- I suspect this need is not common...(yet?) so not a lot is out there.

Is there a way to achieve robust (IE5 through 8) compatibility levels in one fell swoop in MS Edge - with Internet Explorer Mode on - in Windows 11 that was not upgraded from Windows 10?

Thank you in advances, I appreciate any ideas.

I failed to mention that I have also read this post:  [What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/what-does-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-do) along with the Microsoft Docs.

Comment: Yes, IE is gone in Win11. Even if you reinstall it, what you opened is still Edge. And about your needs, I think it may not be possible, just refer to this doc: [Deprecated document modes and Internet Explorer 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/deprecated-document-modes#what-is-document-mode).

Comment: I have not tried this but I think this is the answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-site-list-manager